# How do I find a manual (user Guide) for Ukopp?

Tags: usb, backup

I downloaded Ukopp v.4.7 but I can't make it work? Are there instructions for it?
I found a manual. You people called it a userguide-en.html,  excellent! Lost it? WTF? Now I can't find it! Damn. I hate getting old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [file list of the ukopp package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/ukopp/filelist) indicates it is located at `/usr/share/ukopp/data/userguide-en.html` on your system.

Comment: Thanks Dobey I am new to this. I knew it had to be here some where. And I suspected there might be a read me too. Would it not be help full if I could access these things from the start button? Oh wait I see one of them are here, just miss named. Under HELP there is a Contents that starts the "user guide". And they talk about us using proper English grammar? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Dobey I am new to this. Great hint as to how to find useful stuff. They won't let me vote up your answer yet. I guess the file list is on the web sight, where ever "packages" are? Still trying to get my head around asking for packages before asking to down load an install!

Comment: OK, Does not the word, thanks, indicate I accept your answer? What would be the point of accepting and Down voting an answer? Why do I have to be a 20 before I can indicate an answer is good? Some of the things this grope does baffles me.

Comment: No. There is a check mark next to the answers on a question. You click on the one next to the answer you wish to accept. Upvoting and accepting an answer are not the same. Anyone can upvote (as long as they have enough reputation to vote). Only the person who asked the question can accept an answer. Just saying "thanks" does not result in the site giving reputation points to the person who answered. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers for help on accepting an answer.

Comment: When I click an ^ or a down or a vote I get notice of not enough. So accepting that way gives you points! OK.